# How to update values of the same column values but outside a group

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, for-loop, while-loop

I have a working code, but I need help on one thing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SUPPLIER': ['SUP1', 'SUP1', 'SUP1', 'SUP2', 'SUP2', 'SUP2'],
          'PRODUCT': ['P_100', 'P_100', 'P_100', 'P_100', 'P_100', 'P_100'],
          'PERSON_ID': ['ID_1', 'ID_2', 'ID_3', 'ID_1', 'ID_5', 'ID_7'],
          'TO_SHIP': [57, 57, 57, 40, 40, 40],
          'NEED': [10, 4, 9, 10, 5, 14]})
df
```

I'm looking to make this dynamic, so every time a supplier sends 1 to the person_id with the most need, the need should deduct by 1 for that person_id. So in this case, it should deduct 1 for the 2 rows there with the same person_id and same product.

This one works, except for last part

```
a_group = df.groupby(['SUPPLIER','PRODUCT'])

df["SEND"]  = 0

for name, group in a_group:
    while ((df['TO_SHIP'] > 0) & df['NEED'] != 0).any():
        max_idx = df.groupby(['SUPPLIER', 'PRODUCT'])['NEED'].idxmax()
        df.loc[max_idx, 'SEND'] += 1
        df.loc[df['TO_SHIP'] > 0, 'TO_SHIP'] -= 1
        
        #NEED HELP HERE
        df.loc[max_idx, 'NEED'] -= 1

        
df
```

In the line of code there it only deducts to the person_id in the same group.
How do I deduct one from NEED if it's the same person_ID and Product?

Comment: Can you edit for the desired output? I cannot figure out what is output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly 'How do I deduct one from NEED if it's the same person_ID and Product?'
That is, subtract 1 from 'NEED' if 'PRODUCT', 'PERSON_ID' are the same in both lines?
In any case, I suggest checking these two lines for duplicates. The result, which is placed in a list and checked by the all function (it returns True if all strings are the same).
Let me know more specifically what you want.

```
aaa = df.loc[max_idx, ['PRODUCT', 'PERSON_ID']].duplicated(keep=False).to_list()
if all(aaa):
  df.loc[max_idx, 'NEED'] -= 1
```